# How to Pass a Cookie to an iframe sourced php script?

Tags: php, iframe, cookies

I have a situation where I have two scripts,  one that received variables from the command line and subsequently creates an iframe.  I'm trying to figure out how to pass the variable to the iframe without adding to the src.  For instance:

Script that sets up cookie, "example.php"

```
<?php 
$name = $_GET["name"];
$unique = uniqueid();
setcookie($unique, "John Doe", time()+3600);
?>
<iframe source="http://www.example.com/script.php?cid=<?php echo $unqiue; ?>"></iframe>
```

And then script.php looks like this:

```
<?php 

$cid = $_GET["cid"];
echo $_COOKIE[$cid]'

?>
```

note that example.com is the domain that both scripts are on.  Ideally, the result of calling example.php would result in an iframe containing the words "John Doe", but it's not working.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you thought about using a $_SESSION variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data through cookie if scripts are hosted on same domain.
But it's necessary to set cookie for root path

```
set-cookie: some-key=some-value; path=/;
```

BTW, some browsers will disallow JavaScript communication across sub-domains, even if they have the same top-level domain.